# Showing book cover in public presentation

Tags: publications, copyright, presentation, legal-issues, science-communication

I have a follow up question from my [previous question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/150104/106737) that I thought could be of benefit to others if they had the same question.

I’m giving a public talk for a sci-com event and wanted to show some books that people could read if they were very keen and wanted to learn more.

Is there a copyright problem if I just showed the cover of these books in the presentation? I’d imagine it’s the same as looking at a book at a bookstore, but I could be wrong (has happened before!).

Would I need to at least acknowledge the authors and publishers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, I can't imagine anyone objecting to free advertising. It is just a visible citation, actually. If you think the people at your talk will want to follow up, you could also provide a list of titles and ISBN numbers to make it easy for people to acquire the books.

Whether your presentation could be considered a "republication" of the graphics or not, I can't say. Not a lawyer here. But publishers in general would be happy to have their wares pushed like that. If you were putting those graphics into some (printed or online) publication, you would possibly need permission, but the titles etc would be enough for such purpose anyway.

In any case, in the US, at least, showing the cover or even snippets from the books is probably covered under *fair use* if this is an academic use. In particular, you aren't *reducing* the value of the work by showing its cover.

Comment: True, nor am I getting any profits from it. It’s not an academic talk in the least, it’s to laypeople outside of science and my discipline, so folks would have to be suuuuper keen.